# Distance between different places in USA

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, api

For me to include in my project, I am looking for some [API](https://www.distancecalculator.net/) which can recognize the places and give the output as the distance between two places.

Is there any database that consists of distance matrix between all places in the USA ?

API something similar to [Distance Calculator](https://www.distancecalculator.net/), which is able to recognize all the places and give the distance output for free. [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#prev-license) is being charged. As per this [link](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/open-dataset-containing-distance-between-states-in-the-usa), I cannot enter geo coordinates, I can enter only the place name, it should be able to recognize and find the distance.

Comment: A distance matrix of all "places" in the USA would be enormous, no?

Comment: I would start with geonames.org USA data and work from there. My https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-cityfind.pl does what you want, but for the entire world (it requires a working SQLite3 copy of the geonames db and a helper file found in the same directory).

Comment: Google Maps only charges for a premium plan. What is the amount of calls you need (please [edit] into your question). Also: **What** distance: by car, on foot, as the dove flies...?

Answer (score 5):

National Bureau of Economic Research (NBER) has this data available in its [County Distance Database](https://www.nber.org/data/county-distance-database.html).

Its incredibly detailed, and goes back to 1990.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a list of places with the geocoordinates, you can easily script the distance calculation. This is much easier than calculating *and* storing all the distances ahead of time, include effort for re-calculation when the place dataset changes or updates.

Here's a sample python script ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211266/2327328)):

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

> ```
> 279.352901604
> ```

To get the raw data, see these answers:

- **[OSM](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13066/1511)** more complete, can be all sorts of "places" and not just cities.
- **[Geonames](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13081/1511)** - cities of various sizes, easy CSV data model, easy to filter on US.

Comment: this is such a better answer than mine!